# Merging multiple objects which uses same id

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to merge multiple objects (like Receipts, Reports, etc) with `Collection->merge()`.

**This is the code I used:**

```
$receipts = Receipt::all();
$reports  = Report::all();

$collection = $receipts->merge($reports);
```

This is the result:

[image]

The above screenshot shows two elements, but the third element is missing because it has the same id (id: "1") as the first one. What I'm trying to achieve is to display all three of them as a collection.

**EDIT:**

I need the result to be objects (collection) because I also use the code on my view, where I check the class to determine what to display. Also, I use this function to sort the objects in the collection.

```
    $collection->sort(function($a, $b)
    {
        $a = $a->created_at;
        $b = $b->created_at;
        if ($a === $b) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a > $b) ? 1 : -1;
    });
```

Comment: There is no reason why that merge should not work. Collection is not dependent on any of the properties of the items. Under the hood `merge()` is just an `array_merge` of arrayable items. How does the Report object look?

Answer (score 10):

I know that this is an old question, but I will still provide the answer just in case someone comes here from the search like I did.

If you try to merge two different eloquent collections into one and some objects happen to have the same id, one will overwrite the other. I dunno why it does that and if that's a bug or a feature - more research needed. To fix this just use push() method instead or rethink your approach to the problem to avoid that.

Example of a problem:

```
$cars = Car::all();
$bikes = Bike::all();
$vehicles = $cars->merge($bikes);
// if there is a car and a bike with the same id, one will overwrite the other
```

A possible solution:

```
$collection = collect();
$cars = Car::all();
$bikes = Bike::all();

foreach ($cars as $car)
    $collection->push($car);

foreach ($bikes as $bike)
    $collection->push($bike);
```

Source: https://medium.com/@tadaspaplauskas/quick-tip-laravel-eloquent-collections-merge-gotcha-moment-e2a56fc95889

Answer (score 9):

I know i'm bumping a 4 years old thread but i came across this and none of the answers were what i was looking for; so, like @Tadas, i'll leave my answer for people who will come across this. After Looking at the laravel 5.5 documentation thoroughly i found that [concat](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-concat) was the go-to method.
So, in the OP's case the correct solution would be:

```
$receipts = Receipt::all();
$reports  = Report::all();

$collection = $receipts->concat($reports);
```

This way *every* element in the Report collection will be appended to *every* element in the Receipts collection, event if some fields are identical.

Eventually you could shuffle it to get a more visual appealing result for e.g. a view:

```
$collection->shuffle();
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to go about it is to convert one of your collections to a base collection with **toBase()** method. You can find it in `Illuminate\Support\Collection`

*Method definition:*

```
/**
 * Get a base Support collection instance from this collection.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
 */
public function toBase()
{
    return new self($this);
}
```

*Usage:*

```
$receipts   = Receipt::all();
$reports    = Report::all();

$collection = $receipts->toBase()->merge($reports);
```

Comment: Thanks for this; I spent ages trying to debug and your answer made me realise I wasn't dealing with a standard Collection but in fact an Eloquent Collection.

Answer (score 0):

You could put all collections in an array and use this. Depends on what you want to do with the collection.

```
$list = array();
$list = array_merge($list, Receipt::all()->toArray());
$list = array_merge($list, Report::all()->toArray());
```

Comment: please see my edit. I have also tried that, but I need the results to be Eloquent objects.